# return UIView to portrait after YouTube video in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios4, youtube, orientation

I use UIView with embed UIWebView in order to view YouTube video. When YouTube video playing If the user turn in landscape mode everithing it is ok, but when Done pressed returns in the UIview but in landscape despite that i haved declared shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to portrait only.